# Can I subscribe a topic to another topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to subscribe a existing topic to new topic in Firebase Cloud Messaging, so that all the registered clients of old topic will be registered to new topic.

Example: If I have a FCM topic name **A** and I create a new FCM topic **B**. Can I add topic **A** to topic **B**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only client apps can determine which topics they want to subscribe to in order to receive messages.  You can't route messages going to a topic through another topic.  What you would have to do instead is program the server side code that sends the message to send to multiple topics as needed.